# SQL Substring in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm trying to build a SQL query that will show me all the products that have `products.description IS NULL` but also have a corresponding description in the descriptions table.   So code is always a substring of info.

The `products.code` is a substring of `descriptions.info`, so I'm not sure how to pull this.

**products**

```
id |  code   |  description
--------------------------
1    12345-1      NULL
```

**descriptions**

```
id |  info
---------------------------
1     12345-1_Hammer
```

Comment: Is the substring always the same length

Comment: @nic yes always the same length

Answer (score 2):

You need t o compare `product.info` with `descriptions.info`. If the needed condition is for one to be a substring of the other, it can be done with `LIKE`.

Since there may be more than one descriptions matching (having as substring) a product code, we should use an `EXISTS` subquery:

```
SELECT p.id, p.code
FROM products AS p
WHERE p.description IS NULL
  AND EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM descriptions AS d 
        WHERE d.info LIKE '%' + p.code + '%'
      ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct * 
from products 
join descriptions 
  on products.description is null 
 and products.code + '%' like descriptions.info
```